# Is it a metaphor when a writer describes a character as having arms contorted into knots?

Tags: metaphors

When a writer describes a displeased character as having "arms, lips, eyes contorted into knots", is that actually a metaphor?  Sometimes language feels figurative without a strong metaphorical sense.

Comment: *Hyperbole*....

Answer (score 4):

Per the *OED*, **knot** is a very old word, attested from the year 1000 and coming to us from the Old English *cnotta* meaning a knot in the sense of the tied and intertwined piece of rope.  860 years later the word was applied to thickened nodules of tissue in both plants and animals, so we can talk about **knots** in trees and ****knot****ted muscles.  At the time of this first use, you could say that the usage was metaphoric.  The *OED* marks it "*transferred*," which I think is close to your choice, "*figurative*".  So arm muscles, lips, and maybe the skin around the eyes can be "contorted into knots," and those knots are literal in the transferred meanings.  This is different from the clearly metaphorical, for instance saying that "her eyebrows contorted into crawling caterpillars."

Comment: 'metaphor' is the Greek-rooted word corresponding to the Latin-rooted word 'transfer' both of which translate to 'carry over' or 'bear across', which means that 'metaphor' is a metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's consider the meaning of the word metaphor:
*a figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is not literally applicable.*

Considering that parts of the human body cannot literally contort into knots, the phrase can be considered to be a metaphor.

In the case of your example, which I believe comes from *Inside Out and Back Again*, by Thanhha Lai, the term 'eyes contorted into knots' is used to describe the character's displeasure at having to welcome unwanted guests.

Answer (score 0):

A metaphor is a special substitution of a noun by another expression. Black gold is a metaphor for oil/petroleum. - So it's not a metaphor.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156279)

Comment: @macraf  I hope, now the answer is clear.

Comment: Do metaphors have to substitue for nouns? I thought they could be any part of speech, or in extended metaphors, just an overall idea.

Comment: @sumelic  I gave the simplest definition to give an idea. I didn't want to cover all apects of the term metaphor,  especially as the terms for literary devices have  no definition as the terms in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

The description "arms, lips, eyes contorted into knots" is figurative, and metaphorical:

> **metaphor**
>   A comparison made by referring to one thing as another.

(From *Silva Rhetoricae*, ["metaphor"](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/M/metaphor.htm).)

The arms, lips and eyes are not literally knots, no matter how contorted. Nor are they the knots, real or imagined (imagined in the case of the lump in the throat), defined by the *OED Online* in the transferred senses of 'knot':

> III. transf. A hard or firm mass such as is formed by a knot tied in a string, etc.
>   13. A hard lump in an animal body, either in a softer tissue, or on a smooth surface; a swelling or protuberance in a muscle, nerve, gland, etc.; a knob or enlargement in a bone; a tumour, ganglion, wart, pimple, or the like; the lump that seems to gather in the throat in strong emotion.
>   ....
>   17. A mass formed by the aggregation and cohesion of particles; esp. one that has formed as a hard kernel in the surrounding softer material; a lump, clot, concretion.

["knot, n.1". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104133?rskey=Nk8aDR&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed December 17, 2015).]

Rather, tension and flexure (one thing) of areas of the face and body (lips, eyes, arms; other things) are implicitly *compared by the reference* to those tensed areas as being *contorted into knots*.

---

One set of metaphors involved is the synecdochal reference to visible tension or the lack of it, an aspect of the appearance of bodily features, by naming the features ("arms, lips, eyes"). Thus, the part (an attribute, the appearance of tension) is named by the whole (for example, "eyes"):

> **synecdoche**
>   A whole is represented by naming one of its parts ..., or vice versa ....

(From *Silva Rhetoricae*, ["synecdoche"](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/synecdoche.htm).)

These synecdoches are a type of metaphor: the visible tension of the bodily features is implicitly referred to by naming the feature itself.

Another set of metaphors involved is the comparison made when the contorted bodily features are referred to as 'knots'. This is very close to being a simile, because the comparison between the contorted features and knots is almost explicit--'into' may be read as 'like' without much changing the meaning of the whole:

> arms, lips, eyes contorted **like** knots.

Nonetheless, "very close" and "almost explicit" do not mean 'identical' and 'explicit', so the comparison made by referrring to tense bodily features as "contorted into knots" remains a metaphor.